# Asana User oauth authenticatication in ios apps

Tags: ios, asana

Hi All: I have integrated asana with my ios app using AsanaAPIKey for the user authentication. Now I want to do it using oauth authentication(new requirement).I have searched a lot but haven't found any valuable stuff related to this.Some examples are given in Ruby,but I know nothing about Ruby.Can any one help me out.

Answer (score 1):

We don't have official iOS examples, but in general OAuth on Asana tries to be as close to "typical" as possible. Check out another SO question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374570/whats-the-best-ios-oauth2-framework, for help with iOS and OAuth 2.0, between that and the developer docs https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/authentication I hope you find what you need, but if you run into specific issues please share them!

In the long-term we're hoping to have a proper iOS SDK to make this easier, but given constrained resources I wouldn't hold your breath on that.